# variables in strings with powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, vmware

Im trying to build a variable consisting of several other variables to then include, eg:

```
$myString = "{$_.Name -like "
$myString += $computer[0]
$myString += " -Or $_.Name -like "
$myString += $computer[1]+"}"

Get-VM | Where $myString
```

I've tried all possible combinations with $($myString),$myString,${$myString}, etc ...
It still lists all computers as if there been no filter to it. If i ECHO the Get-VM... it looks prefectly fine and if i cut'n'paste it it works.

Any one got a clue?

Comment: You can't use a string in this way, you need a scriptblock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where-Object filters are scriptblocks.  Script blocks are compiled before runtime, and the variable references in them are fixed in the scriptblock then.  One way to delay that is to use [scriptblock]::create to create the script block after the local variables are set, just before you use it.

```
$myString = "$_.Name -like "
$myString += $computer[0]
$myString += " -Or $_.Name -like "
$myString += $computer[1]

$filter = [scriptblock]::create($myString)

Get-VM | Where $filter
```

Comment: My savior! Thanks for both the explanation of ScriptBlocks and the solution! Worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a scriptblock. It will expand the variables every time you call it. I got Hyper-V installed myself, so I made an example for you:

```
PS > $computer = "DC", "SQL"

$mywherestatement = { $_.Name -like $Computer[0] -or $_.Name -like $Computer[1] }

Get-VM | Where $mywherestatement

Name State CPUUsage(%) MemoryAssigned(M) Uptime   Status
---- ----- ----------- ----------------- ------   ------
DC   Saved 0           0                 00:00:00 Operating normally
SQL  Saved 0           0                 00:00:00 Operating normally



PS > $computer = "CLIENT", "WebDev"

Get-VM | Where $mywherestatement

Name   State CPUUsage(%) MemoryAssigned(M) Uptime   Status
----   ----- ----------- ----------------- ------   ------            
CLIENT Saved 0           0                 00:00:00 Operating normally
WebDev Saved 0           0                 00:00:00 Operating normally
```

If your `$computer` array only contains the names you want to check, I'd use `-contains` instead, because it will work with arrays of any size. Ex:

```
PS > $computer = "DC", "SQL", "CLIENT", "WebDev"

Get-VM | Where { $Computer -contains $_.Name }

Name   State CPUUsage(%) MemoryAssigned(M) Uptime   Status            
----   ----- ----------- ----------------- ------   ------            
CLIENT Saved 0           0                 00:00:00 Operating normally
DC     Saved 0           0                 00:00:00 Operating normally
SQL    Saved 0           0                 00:00:00 Operating normally
WebDev Saved 0           0                 00:00:00 Operating normally
```

Comment: Thanks C.B. and Graimer, the problem is that i can be either 1, 5, 14 computers i want to filter so i have to dynamicaly build the $_.Name -like according to the numbers of computers i want to filter thats why im built in a string, what i didnt mention in my original post is that i do a loop building the string based on number of computers.

Comment: see the updated answer. If you really need to build the string (`$computers` has more then the VMs you want to get), you should use mjolinor's answer. Personally I would've made the script work with `-contains` :)

Comment: Going nuts, what i have is `ForEach($VM in (Get-VM | where $mywherestatement)) {` with the `-contains`it comes up empty, i'll have a go with mjolionr's answer and see if it goes better...

Comment: I'm sorry, but if it didn't work, you didn't use it right. The last example in my answer works perfectly, using `-contains` works perfectly with `ForEach($VM in (Get-VM | where { $Computer -contains $_.Name })) {`.

Comment: No need to be sorry @Graimer, you're help was most appreciated. Can it be because i'm using a wildcard in the `$Computer-array`? This is my result if trying with `-contains`:

`Where-Object : Cannot convert 'dc-cust* ' to the type  System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock' required by parameter 'FilterScript'. Specified method is not supported.`

Comment: Yes, `-contains` needs equal values. Wildcards won't work. If you use wildcards you need something like `where { foreach ($com in $computer) { if ($_.Name -like $com) { $true } } }`